# How to iterate through TreeMap<String,Map<String,String>> and how to print all the keys and values for the same

Tags: java, collections

I am using above Treemap to print all keys and Values but not getting how to iterate through that.please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? 
Show your effort and explain what specifically did not work with your code. As is, it appears that you are just asking us to do it for you.

Comment: Could you please post any code you have tried ? And what specific errors you are getting while attempting to iterate..

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate the map for each entries and get the key and value from the entry.
If you want to get the values from the internal map, you need to iterate it in the same way.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hashMap.put("Internal Key", "Internal Value");

        Map<String, Map<String, String>> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
        treeMap.put("External Key", hashMap);

        for(Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry : treeMap.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            Map<String, String> internalMap = entry.getValue();
            for(Entry<String, String> internalEntry : internalMap.entrySet())
            {
                System.out.println(internalEntry.getKey());
                System.out.println(internalEntry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for replying late but Thanks a lot Somnath...i appreciate ur help :)